# BLE-HM10 SWIFT4 with Arduino

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building an iPhone application that sends a data to bluetooth HM-10.

When I try the switch button, LED is not working. But when I tested it in LightBlue application, it works fine, I don't know where I went wrong.
I would really appreciate the help.

-edited-

"What is not working exactly?" The light won't turn on in pin13, which is built-in led from Arduino Uno. In the Swift application, switching the button on, would send "R" to bluetooth, which triggers led to turn on, likewise when  I switch the button off it would send "r", led turns off.

"What is working?" I can connect to Bluetooth, I found its write characteristic uuid, writevalue function doesn't give me any error.

"What I don't know about?" Whether it's actually sending something or not.

-UPDATED-

Changing from write "withResponse" to "withoutResponse" Solved the problem.
This is the Arduino code I'm using:

```
int message = 0;     //  This will hold one byte of the serial message
int redLEDPin = 13;   //  What pin is the red LED connected to?
int redLED = 0;          //  The value/brightness of the LED, can be 0-255

void setup() {  
  Serial.println("Setup Started");
  Serial.begin(9600);  //set serial to 9600 baud rate
}

void loop(){
    if (Serial.available() > 0) { //  Check if there is a new message
      message = Serial.read(); //  Put the serial input into the message
Serial.println(message);
   if (message == 'R'){  //  If a capitol R is received...
     redLED = 255;       //  Set redLED to 255 (on)
   }
   if (message == 'r'){  //  If a lowercase r is received...
     redLED = 0;         //  Set redLED to 0 (off)
   }

 }   
analogWrite(redLEDPin, redLED);  //  Write an analog value between 0-255
}
```

And this is the swift code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {


    //references to central manager
    let hmBleService = "FFE0"
    let writeCHAR = "FFE1"

    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var writeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!


    //OUTLETS

    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    @IBOutlet weak var uiSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func uiSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if(sender.isOn){

            print("Switch is ON")
            let dataA = "R".data(using: .utf8)
            connectedPeripheral.writeValue(dataA!, for: writeCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            //writeBLEData(string: "R")
        }
        else{
            print("Switch is OFF")
            let dataB = "r".data(using: .utf8)
            connectedPeripheral.writeValue(dataB!, for: writeCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
         //   writeBLEData(string: "r")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue:nil)

    }
//Functions added


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //Attempt to make BLE Connection
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self,selector: #selector(scanForBLEdevice), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        //CLose BLE Connection if it exists
    }



    @objc func scanForBLEdevice(){

        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string:hmBleService)], options: nil)

    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if(peripheral.name != nil){
        print("Found Peripheral name = \(peripheral.name!)")
        }
        else{
            print("Found Peripheral with unknown name")
        }

        //Save reference to the peripheral
        connectedPeripheral = peripheral

        centralManager.stopScan()

        centralManager.connect(connectedPeripheral, options: nil)

    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to the device !")

        hideActivityIndicator()

        connectedPeripheral.delegate = self

        connectedPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("Service = \(String(describing: peripheral.services!.count))")
        for service in peripheral.services!{
            print("Servicee = \(service)")

            let aService = service as CBService
            if service.uuid == CBUUID(string: hmBleService){
                // Discover characteristics for our service
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: aService)

            }

        }

    } 
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        for characteristic in service.characteristics!{
            let aCharacteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic

            if aCharacteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: writeCHAR){
                print("We found our write Characteristic")
                writeCharacteristic = aCharacteristic
            }
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Central Manager Delegates




}
```

What I'm getting in log message :

> centralManagerDidUpdateState: started
>
> Power is ON
>
> 2017-11-11 22:23:14.390142+0300 BlueGreen[708:188886] refreshPreferences:
>
> HangTracerEnabled: 0 2017-11-11 22:23:14.390174+0300
>
> BlueGreen[708:188886] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
>
> 2017-11-11 22:23:14.390187+0300 BlueGreen[708:188886]
>
> refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0
>
> ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0 Found Peripheral name = HMSoft
>
> Connected to the device ! Service = 1 Servicee =
>
> We found our write Characteristic
>
> Switch is ON
>
> Switch is OFF
>
> Switch is ON
>
> Switch is OFF
>
> Switch is ON

Comment: You need to provide a better description than “it doesn’t work”. Whatnoutout do you get?  Have you set breakpoints or used any other debugging techniques to determinenthat your code is executing?

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry I edited the description, well what I'm getting in log are , uuid service for bluetooth, it tells me that I'm connected, I have one characteristic only, and log on print switch on/off message, but when I actually press button, LED on Arduino doesn't turn any light on.

Comment: You are using write with response.  Is that supported by your characteristic? You should implement the `didWrite` peripheral delegate method and check for an error.

Comment: @Paulw11YES!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! the problem was with -write with response- it should be , withoutResponse. :')